# C++ get type of object

Tags: c++, object

I have a C++ application which has the following classes:

- `class AAA`
- `class BBB` inherits from `AAA`
- `class CCC` inherits from `AAA`
- `class DDD` inherits from `CCC`

(All of the classes are marked as `public`)

Now I have the following map:

```
map <DWORD, AAA*>
```

I find an `AAA` object in the `map`, by a `DWORD id`, but now I want to know what is the type of `AAA`:

this will be the logic:

```
if(AAA is BBB)
{
...
}
if(AAA is CCC)
{
...
}
if(AAA is DDD)
{
...
}
```

Do you know how to write it in C++ (without adding a polymorphic function of `getType()`)?

Comment: Why do you need to know the type?

Comment: Why is it required ? If your classes are polymorphic, the compiler would do the rest for you.

Answer (score 7):

Requiring this indicates you are doing it the wrong way. You are trying to replicate something that virtual methods were invented for. Just put a virtual method in your base class.

```
class AAA
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
}

class BBB : public AAA
{
public:
    void DoSomething() { ... }
}

class CCC : public AAA
{
public:
    void DoSomething() { ... }
}

class DDD : public AAA
{
public:
    void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

And in your calling code, your logic is simple:

```
// no need for if() blocks. it's the point of virtual methods.
AAA* somePointer;
...
somePointer->DoSomething();
```

I realize you maybe can't just copy / paste your current "dosomething" code into this. But this is the *pattern* you should be using for this scenario. Perhaps instead of `DoSomething` it makes more sense to have something like `GetSomeInfo`, that the caller can use to do whatever it needs to do. The specific usage of this pattern depends on your context.

Answer (score 4):

If your object is polymorphic (i.e. has at least one virtual function), do a `dynamic_cast<T*>`.

if the result is not `NULL` then you have an object of type `T`. But a virtual function would be a better way to go IMO.

Note: RTTI will need to be [enabled on your compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635123/activate-rtti-in-c) (which it will be in the vast majority of situations)

EDIT: Thanks to @Als and @flipchart for additions

Comment: `dynamic_cast` works for only polymorphic classes. same goes for  `typeid()`,which might give you erroneous results for non-polymorphic hierarchies.

Comment: dynamic_cast for pointers will return null. On references, it will throw an exception. Also note that this requires run time type identification (RTTI)