# Is it possible to prohibit a class from being dynamically casted to?

Tags: c++

I would really want to have a way to say in a declaration of a polymorphic class 'Do not make any code that makes it possible to cast to the type of this class`. Because I know no one is going to dynamically cast to that class, so why compromise efficiency.

```
struct Able{ virtual void do() = 0; };
struct A : Able{
    /* no dynamic_cast for me */
    void do() override{}
};

struct Able2{ void do2() = 0; };
struct B : A, Able2{
    /* no dynamic_cast for me */
    void do2() override{}
};


Able *b = new B;
assert(dynamic_cast<Able2*>(b));
assert(dynamic_cast<A*>(b) == nullptr);
assert(dynamic_cast<B*>(b) == nullptr);
```

My question is premised on the knowledge that with each inheritance from a polymorphic type the invisible *dynamic cast* function gets bigger with one more entry for the type check on the derived class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I disable RTTI selectively in my code base to reduce the binary size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102982/can-i-disable-rtti-selectively-in-my-code-base-to-reduce-the-binary-size)

Comment: @RaymondChen, no. My question is about decreasing the size, and therefore the complexity, of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: IIRC in MSVC it compares native class's string names or something like that. Performance is slow but it is not dependant on the number of classes that inherit from the base class. In general, I do not think that the performance can be dependant on the number of instances of the class. Where did you get the idea that the speed of performance of dynamic cast is dependent on the number of classes?

Comment: The thing is, the way you indicate that a given type is not the target of a dynamic cast is simply by not writing such a dynamic cast anywhere in the program.  `dynamic_cast` doesn't have to do a lot of reasoning over the *target* type; it has to determine whether the *source type* "is a kind of" the target type.  The way to make `dynamic_cast` faster is to give it fewer possible source types to reason about, not fewer target types; i.e. to express the constraint "instances of this type will not be dynamically cast".

Comment: *"My question is premised on the knowledge that with each inheritance from a polymorphic type the invisible dynamic cast function gets bigger with one more entry for the type check on the derived class."*    Actually, the impact of `dynamic_cast` is implementation-dependent.   What you say may be true for one compiler, but not for another.    In any event, a better design goal should be to minimise ANY usage of `dynamic_cast`, rather than try to prevent it for particular source or target types.